# Pass .json config to external js for a grav theme

Tags: javascript, json, twig, grav, particles.js

I'm currently building a [Grav](https://getgrav.org/) theme, in which a `div` should have the `particle` background from [particle.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/).

As stated by the [setup manual](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/#usage), the actual function call in the `js` to render the particles, requires a `config` file in `.json` format

```
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

However, I'm unsure how I can provide the path to the `json` file.
When I tried to pass a regular `html` relative path (like in the example above), the `GET` command in the console returned a 404 error.
When I tried a [Static Asset Path](https://learn.getgrav.org/15/themes/asset-manager#static-assets) using `{{ url("theme://assets/particles.json") }}`, the `GET` returned a 403 (Forbidden) error.

How can I provide the path in the external script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself: Instead of providing a relative path or using the stream functions, you can provide a "semi-relative" path to the theme's asset folder (if you use one):
`/user/themes/<theme-name>/assets/particles.json`

EDIT: In response to the comment by @motizukilucas, I now had a look back at my code (this has been quite a while back, so I try to be as precise as possible; also I don't know if this is still the correct and most elegant way to do it).

For the `.twig` file of the main page that this is used in:

```html
{% set theme_config = attribute(config.themes, config.system.pages.theme) %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-full" lang="{{ grav.language.getActive ?: theme_config.default_lang }}">
    <head>
    ...
    {% do assets.addJs('theme://js/vendor/particles.js', 80) %}
    {% do assets.addJs('theme://js/frontend_js.js', {'priority':80, 'group':'bottom'}) %}
    </head>
    ...
    {% block bottom %}
        {{ assets.js('bottom') }}
    {% endblock %}
```

For the `frontend.js` file (this is where the relative path goes that I mentioned in my initial answer); in the manual this is called `app.js`:

```js
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', '/user/themes/<theme-name>/assets/particles.json', function() {
    console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
  });
```

Then just place the `particles.js` in the `//js/vendor/` folder in the theme (see relative path in the `.twig` file above) and your config (`particles.json`) in the mentioned `/user/themes/<theme-name>/assets/` folder.

Comment: Hi, could you be more detailed on how you managed to get this working? Maybe sharing the html twig section and app.js file.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: @motizukilucas I have extended the answer to reflect the respective paths. Does that clarify things? I hope, it still helps.